# Different result from getYear in IE, when executed on specific dates

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt, date, timezone

I've read about the function getYear in Javascript and how the result differs between browsers. Since I've been maintaining an application which uses the getYear method everywhere, I should probably refactor it to getFullYear.

But I don't understand why the result from the getYear method differs in IE on specific dates, e.g. 28-march-2012.

```
//IE 28-march-2012
var now = new Date();
now.getYear();
//=2012


//IE 29-march-2012
//var now = new Date();
//now.getYear();
//=112
```

I ran this code in IE9, Windows 7, Timezone UTC +1 Amsterdam on 28 march 2012 and 29 march 2012 and just don't understand where the difference is coming from. I hope it's not to obvious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already answered your question: `getYear()` is deprecated and you should use `getFullYear()` instead.

I tried your example and both dates result in 112 for me on IE9. More info about the algorith is available on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/x0a9sc10%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

Comment: That was indeed the fix... I was wrong in localizing the origin of the bug however since the project is built using GWT 2.0.4 which contains this bug: Comment 16, [link](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3132&can=1&q=fixdaylightsavings&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars)